# After effects cc mercury gradient color

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I am new to Afetr Effects and currently trying to work on some water bubble effect using CC Mr. Mercury.

To get that effect I do in AE

New Composition>Solid>CC Mr. Mercury

Now I have realised that the color of the bubbles are based on the color of the solid (same color as the solid). Is it possible to create a gradient color for solid so that the bubbles take after that same gradient color.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that it is doable by applying any gradient effect on the same solid, e.g. 4-color-gradient. Bubbles are going after the gradients now.